# How to resolve the stack corrupt error in Embedded System Programming on ARM Coprtex

Tags: c, arm, embedded

I am trying to program ARM Cortex M0+ MCU. Every alternate time, I get the Stack corrupt error message.
Is there any way to find out what can be the source of error?
I don't know about the way to resolve stack related error

Comment: The point at which the stack error is detected is not likely to be the point at which it was corrupted, so there is no direct means to determine the source.  Moreover detecting stack errors is not part of the C language, and must be part of your runtime environment - we have no way of determining how it is detecting the error.  Showing us the code that causes the error and the verbatim error text would make a better question.

Comment: stack corruption may arise from heap memory extends and violates to the stack memory are. Be careful about your malloc or return pointer usages. You can check your code putting blocking loops to the initialization codes. Do you have asynchronous interrupt handler etc. in you code? You can separate levels by putting while(1) blocks; and see if exception occurs or not. So consecutively try suspected lines and find the problematic line.

Answer (score 1):

One best practice is to use a static analysis tool to make sure that you are not trampling any stack or heap variables.

Try clang analyzer as an easily available open source solution.

Alternatively, if you can run your code on a host machine, you can use gdb or valgrind to try and find memory errors.